# How to compare two string variable with python

Tags: python-3.x

here is a code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

import os

home = 'mu'
away = 'mcity'
result = 'N'

mon_fichier = open("fichier.txt", "a")

if os.stat('fichier.txt').st_size == 0:  
    mon_fichier.write("chelsea \n")
    mon_fichier.write("arsenal \n")
    mon_fichier.write("arsenal \n")
    mon_fichier.write("mu \n")
    mon_fichier.write("mcity \n")
    mon_fichier.write("N \n")
    mon_fichier.write("liv \n")
    mon_fichier.write("tot \n")
    mon_fichier.write("liv \n")
    
    mon_fichier.close()
else:
    mon_fichier = open("fichier.txt", "r")
    count = 0
    
    for line in mon_fichier:
          count += 1
          if line == home:
              print(line.strip())
              
    mon_fichier.close()
```

The goal is to compare a string variable named home with all the lines of the file fichier.txt. If in the file we have "mu" The output should print "mu" in the terminal but in my case I have no answer.

Comment: Maybe you should use `strip()` *before* comparing the strings?

Comment: try printing what you read exactly from the file. e.g. a string `"mu \n"` won't compare equal to `"mu"`...